# Pointing AX 2012 to a new DB Server

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I changed the Database Server from Microsoft Dynamics AX Server configuration, restarted AOS on prompt and saved the configuration as a file. But when I run the file I'm getting the below error:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Dynamics AX Error
---------------------------
The command-line parameter -compressionminsize=1024 is invalid. Check the spelling and start Microsoft Dynamics AX again.
---------------------------
OK 
---------------------------
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand that this is not an exact programming question, but there is no other stackexchange site with Dynamics AX users.
Some mod can migrate this to superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new client config via https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh389774.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**Edit:** I just realized the link I provided is to create a client config and use it for reporting services. For this question, you would just skip step `#8` in the link.

Comment: Thanks Alex, That was the exact issue.